# Lottery Game in java

Tags: java

I am having issues writing a java program for a lottery game the program that i have written works but i cant get the sum part to work right. i need it to add each and every single digit for example if the result prints 234,456,345 I need to add 2+3+4+4+5+6+3+4+5 and then return the sum but what i get is 234+456+345 any help will be good.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LotteryDraw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int game;
        int times;
        int randNum; 
        int lotNum;
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("Which lottery game do you want to play!");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 for Pick 3");
        System.out.println("Enter 4 for Pick 4");
        System.out.println("Enter 5 for Pick 5");
        game = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("How many games would you like to play? ");
        times = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Thank you! The numbers selected were: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            lotNum = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < game; j++)
            {
                randNum = (new java.util.Random()).nextInt(10);
                lotNum = (lotNum * 10) + randNum;
                System.out.print(randNum);
            }
            System.out.println();
            sum += lotNum;   
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of the numbers of all games: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying the lotNum * 10?  That's the reason that you're ending up with 234+456+345 instead of 2+3+4+4+5+6+3+4+5.

Comment: Please check the code that is included in your question. It seems it is corrupted.

Comment: thank you so much gargantubrain that help...

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED CODE:**

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LotteryDraw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int game;
        int times;
        int randNum; 
        int lotNum;
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("Which lottery game do you want to play!");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 for Pick 3");
        System.out.println("Enter 4 for Pick 4");
        System.out.println("Enter 5 for Pick 5");
        game = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("How many games would you like to play? ");
        times = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Thank you! The numbers selected were: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            lotNum = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < game; j++)
            {
                randNum = (new java.util.Random()).nextInt(10);
                lotNum = (lotNum * 10) + randNum;
                System.out.print(randNum);
                sum+=randNum;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of the numbers of all games: " + sum);
    }
}
```